# Scope for a local variable in FOR LOOP in java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am writing a java code to pull data from database using hibernate and `Spring MVC` as Rest API.I have created the configuration mapping etc.The stdout shows correct output from the database but I have to get it as a `JSON` object.I have the DAO classes written.My code is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{userid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody IterationInfo getIterationInfoInJSON(@PathVariable int userid) 
{

    Configuration con = new Configuration();
    con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory SF = con.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session= SF.openSession();
    Transaction TR = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query=session.createQuery("from IterationInfo");
    List<IterationInfo> list=query.list();
    for(IterationInfo iterationinfo1 : list)
    {
        System.out.println("Iteration id"+iterationinfo1.getIterationid());
        System.out.println(iterationinfo1.getIterationname());
        System.out.println(iterationinfo1.getProjectid());
        System.out.println(iterationinfo1.getIterationenddate());
        System.out.println(iterationinfo1.getIterationstartdate());
        iterationinfo1.setIterationid(iterationinfo1.getIterationid());
        iterationinfo1.setIterationname(iterationinfo1.getIterationname());
        iterationinfo1.setProjectid(iterationinfo1.getProjectid());
        iterationinfo1.setIterationenddate(iterationinfo1.getIterationenddate());
        iterationinfo1.setIterationstartdate(iterationinfo1.getIterationstartdate());
    }
    TR.commit();
    session.close();
    SF.close();

    return iterationinfo1;
}
```

Error is `iterationinfo1` cannot be resolved to a variable.
Any answers will be helpful.

Comment: So you actually want to return the last object in `list`? If so, `return list.get(list.size() - 1);` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks mate...worked...I have got another question.I have multiple entries in the database so how can I return multiple json results??

Comment: Can you explain, why you are looping over the list?

Comment: @Akshay, that would be another question and should be asked separately.

Comment: what is the purpose of those `iterationinfo1.set...` lines? To me it looks like you are just re-writing the same already set value in your object.

Comment: using for loop System.out gives the entire result set from database in console.I want it in json.The above code gives me the result of the first entry of the database in json and entire result in console

Comment: So do you want whole result in JSON or only first record?

Comment: The entire result from the database in JSON

Comment: @SujitKumar looping over list trying to get the entire set of result from database.

Comment: @jhamon iterationinfo1.set..is to set the values to the json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpful

```
@RequestMapping(value="{userid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<IterationInfo> getIterationInfoInJSON(@PathVariable int userid) 
{

Configuration con = new Configuration();
con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory SF = con.buildSessionFactory();
Session session= SF.openSession();
Transaction TR = session.beginTransaction();
Query query=session.createQuery("from IterationInfo");
List<IterationInfo> list=query.list();
for(IterationInfo iterationinfo1 : list)
{
    System.out.println("Iteration id"+iterationinfo1.getIterationid());
    System.out.println(iterationinfo1.getIterationname());
    System.out.println(iterationinfo1.getProjectid());
    System.out.println(iterationinfo1.getIterationenddate());
    System.out.println(iterationinfo1.getIterationstartdate());
    iterationinfo1.setIterationid(iterationinfo1.getIterationid());
    iterationinfo1.setIterationname(iterationinfo1.getIterationname());
    iterationinfo1.setProjectid(iterationinfo1.getProjectid());
    iterationinfo1.setIterationenddate(iterationinfo1.getIterationenddate());
    iterationinfo1.setIterationstartdate(iterationinfo1.getIterationstartdate());
}
TR.commit();
session.close();
SF.close();

return list;
}
```

Comment: The method which I have written public @ResponseBody IterationInfo getIterationInfoInJSON returns data in json so there is no need to convert or use JSONArray.The only question was I want the entire database result .Using above code gives me the result of only first entry of the database.

Comment: Do you mean `List<IterationInfo>`?

Comment: Yes..It returns the entire result in console using Sys.out but the json returned is only for first entry.

Comment: @Akshay, your method have return type as `IterationInfo` which is single entity. To get the whole list you should return the `List<IterationInfo>`.

Comment: I have modified my answer which you required in your case. If that helped you, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged this with spring-mvc, it is generally a bad practice to connect to the database directly from a controller. You should have a service method that gets called from a controller and that method communicates with your dao or repo classes.

Comment: Yes but now its just a POC.During the main development we will definately do that!

Comment: Though you are mentioning good practice but this does not answer the OP's question.